# How can I customize Google Voice behavior when forwarding calls?

Tags: google-voice, iphone

I setup my Google Voice number to forward to my AT&T cell phone number. There are two features of the forwarding behavior I'm not very fond of:

1. When someone calls, they get a recorded voice asking for their
   name.  People tend to assume this is voicemail, and not realize that
   my phone is ringing, and after they follow the instructions I will
   be picking up.
2. When I pick up the phone, it tells me the name of the person
   calling and asks whether I'd like to answer the call or send it to
   voice mail (I'd rather it simply assume I'd like to answer so I
   didn't have to wait or bother with the keypad).

I don't think its relevant, but I'm using an iPhone 4.  Is there anyway to setup Google Voice call forwarding which avoids either of these two issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice), go to `Settings | Calls` and turn **off** "Call Screening".

Callers will no longer be asked to say their name, nor will you be prompted to "press 1" to accept the call.

More information at [Google Support](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115083).

Comment: Thanks! Its more than a little embarrassing that I wrote this question before thoroughly exploring all the options! RTFM as they say.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up caller groups and have Anonymous callers go through screening and those in your Google Voice "Group(s)" are answered when picked up... I have a group called "LeftNoMsg" and people that call but left no message get a different recording stating...

"You have went directly to our voice mail box, It appears you have called before but left no message. So please leave a message this time and I will get back with you promptly."

I have call screening set up as default. I also have groups called Vip, Family, Friends, Etc. and those are set up to answer (without screening).